# What variants of array declaration syntax are available in PHP 5.4?

Tags: php, arrays, deprecated

On the PHP documentation page for arrays, the example code given is the following:

```
<?php
$array = array(
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo",
);

// as of PHP 5.4
$array = [
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo",
];
?>
```

Does that mean that the first code is invalid in PHP 5.4, or is the second code just an alternative?

Comment: The shorthand notation is available starting with 5.4 but both remain valid.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php and http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.deprecated.php should answer your question. As would running the code in a 5.4 environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first code is still valid. The second notation is just a shorter and more convenient alternative.

Answer (score 0):

As others noted the first one is valid. The second one is shorter version.

Here are the pros and cons for second version:

> ```
> Pro
>
>   Good for framework development when dealing with long parameterlists
>   Other web languages have similar syntax
>   Readable
>
> Contra
>
>   Yet another alias
>   Would take distinctness from []
>   Not searchable through search engines
>   Unreadable
>   Patch may be difficult to maintain in future
> ```

from [PHPWiki](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/shortsyntaxforarrays)

Comment: I want to smack whoever said the second version is "unreadable" in the head.